# Find convergence of series ....

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How do we find the convergence of $$ s_n = \sin (1!) +  \frac {\sin (2!)}{1!} + \frac {\sin (3!)}{2!} + \frac {\sin (4!)}{3!} +... \frac {\sin (n+1!)}{n!} $$ 
I was thinking of using convergence tests but they are used only for infinite series.  I tried to use the ratio test $ \frac {a_{(n+1)}}{a_n}$ but the series does not go to infinite so I couldn't use it. Meanwhile I also tried to simplify it, but still I couldn't get something concrete.

Comment: Why bother testing it at all? Don't all finite series converge anyway?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

$$\left|\frac{\sin((k+1)!)}{k!}\right|\le\frac{1}{k!}$$

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane : is there a way to better bound the summation than $\frac{e \Gamma (n,1)}{\Gamma (n)}$. I am really just curious. Thanks for helping. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sin(n+1)!}{n!}\leq \frac{1}{n!}\\S_{n}=\sin(1!) +\frac{\sin(2!)}{1!} +\frac{\sin(3!)}{2!} +
\frac{\sin(4!)}{3!} +...+\frac{\sin(n+1)}{n!} \\\leq |\sin(1!) +\frac{\sin(2!)}{1!} +\frac{\sin(3!)}{2!} +\frac{\sin(4!)}{3!} +...+\frac{\sin(n+1!}{n!}| \\\leq |\sin(1!)| +|\frac{\sin(2!)}{1!}| +|\frac{\sin(3!)}{2!}| +|\frac{\sin(4!)}{3!}\ +...+|\frac{\sin(n+1)!}{n!}|\\\leq \frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}\\\leq 1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}+... =e^1$$ So, it converges.

Comment: @daryakhosrotash. I wonder if you did not want to say $< e$ instead of $e^n$.

Comment: Upper bounding the partial sums of a real valued series is not enough to show the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

Finally one I can answer!

Note that $\forall x, |sin(x)|\le1$, thus $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\sin((n+1)!)}{n!}\le\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{|\sin((n+1)!)|}{n!}\le\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{n!}$

The same applies for the first $n$ terms of the sequence

Comment: Upper bounding the partial sums of a real valued series is not enough to show the series converges.